# What is a good graphing software?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

What is a good graphing software ? The one that has the ability to accept an equation (linear, quadratic, etc.) from users and output a graph for that equation (software equivalnet of T1-84 graphing calculator).

Comment: I use gnuplot often.  It's not very good but it's free and dependable! http://www.gnuplot.info/  I'm an ex-TI-81-user turned perl-programmer so take this suggestion with some salt or sugar if you please.

Answer (score 7):

Grapher.app on any Mac from the past few years; [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/), [GrafEq](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/), WinPlot, AutoGraph, [Geometer's Sketchpad](http://www.dynamicgeometry.com/), [TI SmartView](http://education.ti.com/educationportal/sites/US/productDetail/us_smartview.html) (official TI-84 emulator), ...

Answer (score 7):

You could also consider Desmos (web-based and free): https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 2):

This is old but it randomly appeared on the Top Questions list, and I can't help recommending [Spacetime](http://www.spacetime.us/windows/). While Octave/Sage/GeoGebra/Matplotlib-and-friends, etc. are quite a bit more powerful, spacetime feels a lot more like your Ti calculator: you can do basic things like plotting, fitting lines, evaluating eigenvalues, etc. very quickly and easily, without having to learn much syntax at all. It also has an iphone version which is a whole load cheaper than a Ti calculator, but probably quite a bit more powerful :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [onlinefunctiongrapher.com](http://onlinefunctiongrapher.com) it is web-based and does not require java or flash.

Comment: I like [FooPlot](http://www.fooplot.com/) myself.