# What is a good graphing program and code to graph $F(x)=\prod_{p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}$ for prime $p$.

Tags: prime-numbers, soft-question, graphing-functions, math-software, python

What is a good graphing program and code to graph $F(x)=\prod_{p \leq x} \frac{p-1}{p}$ where the product is taken over all primes $p \leq x$ and $x$ is an integer? I have been doing research on this an have come up with inconclusive results. I am mostly looking for something that is simple (online and does not need to be downloaded) but gets the job done. Nonetheless, if there is not such a program, please try to specify with Python, if possible.

Comment: The numerators of your $F(x)$ are in [A076359](https://oeis.org/A076359), and denominators are in [A076358](https://oeis.org/A076358). Btw, there is tag [tag:math-software].

Answer (score 1):

*I have few suggestions:*

- Wolfram Mathematica
- Python (SymPy)
- *other recommended things*

---

### Mathematica

I use `Wolfram Mathematica`. It is not a free software, but you can **use a free version of it online**.

That is, you can write [an online wolfram mathematica notebook](https://www.open.wolframcloud.com/view/newNotebook?ext=nb) and then click run (shift + enter).

Your function would be something like:

```
ListPlot[Table[Product[(Prime[i] - 1)/(Prime[i]), {i, 1, PrimePi[x]}], {x, 1, 1000}]]
```

But the above code is slow because we are calculating every product from the beginning. Instead of being inefficient like above, we can write a recursive function that stores and uses previous values like so:

```
f[x_, y_] := If[x == y, (y - 1)/(y), 1];
F[x_] := F[x] = If[x == 1, 1, F[x - 1]*f[x, Prime[PrimePi[x]]]];
ListPlot[Table[F[x], {x, 1, 10^4}]]
```

Entering the new code into the above link I gave you, will give you:

[image]

You can also [customize the `ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) to look nice, and then export it as pdf or image.

There is [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) for questions regarding this software. You might not even need to ask questions there, as the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) is already very good and full of examples.

In the above example, `F[x_] := ...` is a function definition and `F[x_] := F[x] = ...` tells the function to remember (store) the values so it does not need to re-evaluate it every time you call it for the same `x` value. Note that if you change the definition of the function, the new values will not update over the old stored ones. You need to clear them by running `ClearAll[F];` once, which removes the definition of the `F` and everything associated with it, such as the stored values `F[x]`.

---

### Python

If you want to stay inside `python`, look into `SymPy` (e.g. [SymPy's number theory](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html)) and `matplotlib`.

Equivalent code to the above code:

```
from sympy import primepi
from sympy import sieve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

limit = 10**4

sieve.extend(limit)

def f(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return (y-1)/y
    return 1

F = [1]
for x in range(2, limit):
    F.append(F[-1]*f(x, sieve[primepi(x)]))

plt.axis([None, None, 0.059, 0.0975])
plt.plot(F)
plt.show()
```

Produces an equivalent image:

[image]

Where notice that the `Mathematica` automatically restricted the y-axis to make the plot look "pretty" (in the previous image),

where in `python` I added `plt.axis([None, None, 0.059, 0.0975])` to achieve the same effect here. (Though, it looks like here x-axis is a bit shorter - *but anything can be customized in both codes if you want, just explore the documentation.*)

---

**Alternatives**

For alternatives, check similar questions already asked here, such as:

- [What is a good graphing software?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26903/318073)
- [Draw customized (calculus) graphs like these?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32512/318073)
- [A good, free, graphics package for mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5837/318073)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [PARI/GP in a browser](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html). Use this code

```
F(x)=prod(n=1,primepi(x),1-1/prime(n));
plot(x=10,200,F(x))
```

to define and plot your function. If you run the
program locally with graphics enabled you can replace
`plot` with `ploth` to get a high resolution plot.
This can be saved in a graphics format such as PDF.